# Turbulence forming between the coaches of rail

Tags: aerodynamics, turbulence

is there any specific reason why rail coaches are connected by a rubber sheet; not of any other material ?

I watched a documentary on trains (Discovery Channel) which said it connecting coaches by rubber sheets reduces turbulence that are formed between the rail coaches. What exactly does it mean ?

Comment: Isn't flexibility the biggest issue here?

Comment: @Bernhard He may be asking "why connect them at all?", looking at the turbulence part. Turbulence makes sense; but just being able to connect them is the primary reason IMO.

Comment: A note: MBTA local trains(Aside from the Green Line) don't have rubber sheets. They have a few metal bars for emergency use. Since there really is no need to move from one cabin to another in these trains, the rubber sheet is absent. This points to the primary reason being traversibility; not turbulence. Discovery Channel is a bit..well..*shady* when it comes to facts.